Overlayfs hide lower overlay
While working with overlayfs, I noticed what looks like either a bug or, as far as I have found, an undocumented behaviour.
If on a system, an overlay is mounted on the a parent directory of an already mounted overlay. The lower one disappears and the root filesystem gets exposed.
Is this expected, am I holding it wrong or is this indeed maybe a bug ?
Here is a "demonstration" of the behavior
$ tree
.
├── mount
├── ov1
│   └── folder1
│       └── test
├── ov2
│   └── folder2
│       └── test
├── root
│   ├── folder1
│   │   └── test
│   └── folder2
│       └── test
├── work1
└── work2

10 directories, 5 files

$ cat ov1/folder1/test
ov1/folder1/test
$ cat ov2/folder2/test
ov2/folder2/test
$ cat root/folder1/test
root/folder1/test
$ cat root/folder2/test
root/folder2/test

$ sudo mount -t overlay overlay -o"lowerdir=root/folder1,upperdir=ov1/folder1,workdir=work1" root/folder1

$ cat ov1/folder1/test
ov1/folder1/test
$ cat ov2/folder2/test
ov2/folder2/test
$ cat root/folder1/test
ov1/folder1/test
$ cat root/folder2/test
root/folder2/test

$ sudo mount -t overlay overlay -o"lowerdir=root,upperdir=ov2,workdir=work2" root

$ cat ov1/folder1/test
ov1/folder1/test
$ cat ov2/folder2/test
ov2/folder2/test
$ cat root/folder1/test
root/folder1/test
$ cat root/folder2/test
ov2/folder2/test

$ mount | grep overlay
overlay on /home/grandpa/.local/tmp/overlay_bug_test/root/folder1 type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=root/folder1,upperdir=ov1/folder1,workdir=work1)
overlay on /home/grandpa/.local/tmp/overlay_bug_test/root type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=root,upperdir=ov2,workdir=work2)


I showed the file hierarchy in the first command, then cated all the test files without mount, after the first overlay mount and after the second to show that after the first mount it is as expected but after the second the content of the root has reappeared.
Yes globstar is nonstandard but you still understood what it meant so I don't get what the issue is.

Other than the option names suggest, overlayfs works on filesystems, not directory trees. Is that perhaps the source of your confusion?

Yeah I get that overlayfs works on file systems, but from my understanding and experience with them, you can stack them by mounting multiple overlayfs' on top of each other, though in this case, when you mount an overlay on top of the parent directory of another overlay's mount point, the lower one seems to be bypassed

(My first commet looks a bit weird now because some random person told me that my question wasn't clear enough because I used cat **/test instead of individually catting the files - and apparently deleted their comments since...
So my "I don't get what the issue is" is directed to them)

It was me. You had reacted to my comments, so they were no longer needed; so I deleted them. You said I "still understood", but no. The issue was I did not understand, I guessed. Now there is nothing to guess and the question is fine.

With overlayfs, when you pick a lowerdir, you do not pick a directory tree from the VFS that you usually interact with. Instead, you select both the directory and the actual filesystem it resides on. Another filesystem is mounted in a subdirectory of that directory? Overlayfs does not care. It operates on a single filesystem (per lowerdir/upperdir).
It’s a bit like mount --bind, if you’re familiar with that. Turns out this isn’t easy to explain or I’m bad at explaining it, but I hope you get it with this.
So, yes, this is expected, though perhaps unintuitive at first glance.

I had thought it might be something like that. Do you know if this is a conscious implementation choice or if it is due to some limitation ?
Is it that all mounts are done in a way that is unaware of the view of the VFS we have as users ?
I am not sure I get what the similarity with a bind mount is, but the explanation about overlayfs not interacting with the VFS the way I expected it to made the behavior make sense

@grandpa Almost certainly a conscious implementation choice, because it would mean lots and lots of edge cases simply vanish. Especially surrounding stacked overlayfs’s. The maximum is two.
